# How to only do string manupilation on column of pandas that have 4 digits or less?

Tags: python, pandas

I have df that looks like this:

```
   numbers
0      111
1    22222
2     3423
```

I want to apply a `0` to the beginning of any 4digit number, how do I do this?

New df should look like this:

```
   numbers
0      111
1    22222
2    03423
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `rjust`

```
df=df.astype(str)
df.loc[df.numbers.str.len()==4,'numbers']=df.numbers.str.rjust(5,'0')
df
Out[370]: 
  numbers
0     111
1   22222
2   03423
```

Answer (score 2):

#### [`pandas.Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html)

```
df = df.astype(str)  # Making sure these are strings

mask = df.numbers.str.len() == 4
df.loc[mask, 'numbers'] = df.loc[mask, 'numbers'].str.zfill(5)

df

  numbers
0     111
1   22222
2   03423
```

Comment: what is more advantageous with this method versus the below user?

Comment: Preference.  This one is a specialized version of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

df['ResultingColumn'] = ['0'+str(x) for x in df['StringColumn'] if len.df['ResultingColumn'] == 4]